# How to check in C++ whether windows notifications are turned on or off?

Tags: windows, notifications, toast

I want to check in C++ whether windows toast notifications are turned on or off? if they are turned off I want to show alert Window.

Tried searching Microsoft documentation for same but could not find any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if there is a specific one for toasts but [`SHQueryUserNotificationState`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/shellapi/nf-shellapi-shqueryusernotificationstate) is the generic way to query.